# No reimbursement for travel expenses after two months

Tags: germany, reimbursement

I applied for a software development job in another city in Germany. When I was invited to an on-site interview they also stated that I would get reimbursed for my travel expenses. I paid for a second class train ticket and a few extra bucks for a ticket inside the city (to get from the main station to the company office and back). When I was there I handed in the form for reimbursement and the receipt for both tickets.
After a few interviews with different people at the company I decided that I did not longer want to work for them and I messaged them saying that I was withdrawing my application. This was prior to any feedback from them. They reacted quite professionally and they didn't seem unfriendly in their reply.

However, two months later I still did not receive any reimbursement. I would like to message them and remind them about our agreement that I would get reimbursed for my expenses.

I believe I have a right to reimbursement according to §670 BGB (German Civil Code) and they stated that I would get reimbursed anyways (I have this in my inbox still).

---

**How can I put the wording in my email so that it reads like a friendly reminder and nothing more?** I would also like to ask them *when* I would get the money but I'm worried this might not be received well.

Comment: Hi, Any update on the travel reimbursement?

Comment: Ha! Yeah maybe I'm taking this too seriously... I'm curious what others might think though

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't called or sent an e-mail, I think that should be your first step. Hanlan's Razor should apply here; never assume malice when stupidity/incompetence can explain something. Most likely, the person in charge of filing your reimbursement just misplaced it, and a polite reminder will be all it takes to get it moving.

Comment: I didn't contact them about this yet. I don't really assume malice so far. I'm just afraid that it might sound like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you check your spam folder, account statement etc., to make sure you really haven't got it yet.
2. Send them a quick reminder. "Thanks for your interest and interviewing me on xx/xx/xxxx. At the time you offered reimbursement for my travel expenses but I haven't received anything yet. Would you mind providing an update?" Since it's Germany can actually be a little more direct.

If it's only a small-ish amount I would let it go since it's been two months already. It's probably just an oversight on their part. You are certainly  entitled to the payment but you also need to assess whether it's worth the extra bother and asking the company to do a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: +1. I would add, don't mention the Civil Code section or describe their duty to pay you as any sort of legal obligation in your first email. If you want to go all cop / lawyer on them, wait until your third email.